# python code in Apache Nifi ExecuteStreamCommand UnicodeEncodeError : surrogates not allowed

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, apache-nifi, stdin

I have some chinese words in csv file. I through nifi ExecuteStreamCommand processor to input the csv file. And I get the UnicodeEncodeError: surrogates not allowed. I make sure the csv file is utf-8. And the problem should be about the chinese words because when I deleted these words, I don't have error.

Example csv:

```
SAP_MATERIAL,GENERIC_ARTICLE,DIM1,DIM2,EAN_UPC,CURRENT_YEAR,CURRENT_SEASON,ARTICLE_DESC,CHINESE_DESC,STYLE,GENDER_CODE,LOCAL_GENDER,LOCAL_GENDER_DESC,SBU_CODE,SBU_DESC,COLLECTION,COLLECTION_DESC,BRAND,SBU_SUB_CODE,SBU_SUB_DESC,CN_RETAIL_PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC,SBU_DESC_CN,SBU_SUB_DESC_CN,TBL_CATEGORY,AGE_GROUP,SAP_GENDER_DESC,COLOR_GROUP_DESC,keep,df_cal
TB027657626105500M,TB0276576261,055,00M,885641855420,2012,SS,"[TB0276576261]KENNBNK GLADIATOR RED,FQ",,027657,W,,,906,TB Tree Footwear,X,,TI,9AR,TB_FT_Women,,TB Tree 鞋履,TB_鞋履_女款,Footwear,,W - WOMEN,RED,1,333
TB027657626105500M,TB0276576261,055,00M,885641855420,2012,SS,"[TB0276576261]KENNBNK GLADIATOR RED,FQ",,027657,W,,,906,TB Tree Footwear,X,,TI,9AR,TB_FT_Women,,TB Tree 鞋履,TB_鞋履_女款,Footwear,,W - WOMEN,RED,2,333
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
df = df.drop_duplicates(
        subset=df.columns.difference(['keep']),keep = False)
df = df[(df.keep == '2')]
df.drop(['keep','df_cal'],axis = 1,inplace = True)


df.to_csv(sys.stdout,index = None)
```

Here are some pictures to help everyone understand the situation.

This is the file before input the ExecuteStreamCommand processor:
[image]
This is the error:
[image]
ExecuteStreamCommand processor setting:
[image]
mergeContent processor setting:
[image]

I tried to update my code but still got the same error

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
df = df.drop_duplicates(
        subset=df.columns.difference(['keep']),keep = False)
df = df[(df.keep == '2')]
df.drop(['keep','df_cal'],axis = 1,inplace = True)
for column in df:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(str).str.encode('utf-8')

df.to_csv(sys.stdout,index = None)
```

How can I fix the error?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this? - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22610

Comment: yes, I checked. but I can't do this in this case. when I followed this solution , I got the error 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'. 
This is my code: ```for column in df.columns:
df[column] = df[column].encode('utf-8',errors='surrogatepass')```

Comment: To convert Excel to CSV using `ExecuteStreamCommand`, I have used something like this, see whether you can relate  - `wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=sys.stdin.read(),logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8',engine='xlrd')`

Comment: thank you for the solution. I updated the code but still not work. This is my update:
```df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin,encoding='utf-8',engine='python') df.to_csv(sys.stdout,encoding='utf-8',index = None)```

Comment: And I found that this problem is only on nifi. I can run this code in local and don't have error.